# Lowering the key of a song by a semitone

Tags: key, key-signatures, transposition

What does lowering the key of a song by a semitone exactly mean? If a song is for example in F major, and you lower the key by a semitone, do you lower every note by a semitone? This becomes E G♭ A♭ A B D♭ E♭ E, which sounds the same as E major, but E major doesn't have flats but sharps. So in what key would it be? Or do you add one more flat in the key signature, so that F major becomes B♭ major?

Comment: Keys run in a circle and aren't 'higher' or 'lower' than each other. If someone talks about "lowering the key", they're speaking informally - combining the ideas of "changing the key" and "lowering the pitch".

Comment: To get the enharmonic spelling right, lower the piece by a minor second rather than by any old semitone.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, that is what lowering the key of a song by a semi-tone means. You transpose every note down one half-step. Changing from the key of F major to the key of Bb major would actually be *raising* the key by a fourth (five semitones), although it's clearer to say "transposing up a fourth".

Gb is enharmonic to F#, Ab to G#, etc. If you replace each flat with its enharmonic sharp, you'll end up with the key signature for E major.

Side note:

If you wanted, you could instead spell "E" as "Fb", also "A" as "Bbb" and "B" as "Cb". Then you would have a key signature for Fb major, which is enharmonic to E major. Of course, no one ever does this, but I thought it might help explain why your brain seemed to go in a valid direction and still was confusing. Instead of changing some letter names and then adding flats to other letters, you would either change **none** of the letters and add a flat to all of the existing letter names, or change **all** of the letter names down by one and add sharps when necessary to make sure the new key is major. That's a general guide to transposing keys.

Answer (score 9):

You're on the right track, but adding to Todd's answers each note gets dropped down by a semitone, it puts the song into key E. Thus each new note must belong to that key, and that key contains *one of each letter name*.

Looking at your idea, you'll see there's no F, two As and two Es. It'd be a nightmare to try to re-write the music that way!. So, the notes will be from E F# G# A B C# D#. Note - one of each. What's actually happened is that each letter name before has dropped by one - F to E, Bb to A, D to C# etc. Yes, effectively each original has been flattened, but in some keys (E is one) the notes take on new names. Like that 'Db' gets known as 'C#'.

Certainly what you *do not* do, is add another flat. That would sort of put it into Bb, but if the notes didn't change it would only have one affected note, and if they did change down a semitone, you'd end up with key E, but with a flattened 5, which wouldn't work at all.

Answer (score 5):

To work out what to replace each note by, it is better to lower each note by the same *interval* rather than some *number of semitones*. In this case, you want to transpose from F to E. This entails lowering by a minor second. (Because each note is lowered by a second, that means that it gets replaced by a note whose letter name is one letter further down.)

This means that notes get replaced as follows:

E --> D#

D --> C#

C --> B

Bb --> A

A --> G#

G --> F#

F --> E

The same applies to any chromatic notes, too. Thus a D flat would become C, whereas a C sharp would become B sharp.